# How can I fix this "forEach of undefined" error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` when I try to run this code:

```
for (let Sıra_Numarası = 0; Sıra_Numarası < Anlamlar_Liste.length; Sıra_Numarası++) {
    Anlamlar_Liste[Sıra_Numarası].ozelliklerListe.forEach(Özellik => {
        Tepki_Mesajı.addField(`${Sıra_Numarası + 1}. ${Özellik.tam_adi}`, Anlamlar_Liste[Sıra_Numarası].anlam, true)

        console.log(Özellik.tam_adi)
        console.log(Anlamlar_Liste[Sıra_Numarası].ozelliklerListe)
    })
}
```

`Tepki_Mesajı.addField ()` method is for add new field to Discord Embed message, and I think failure is here, because `console.log ()` works successfully and I get data in JSON API.

And value of `Anlamlar_Liste` in API is:

```
[
  {
    "anlam_id": "4798",
    "madde_id": "9592",
    "anlam_sira": "1",
    "fiil": "0",
    "tipkes": "0",
    "anlam": "Çocuğu olan kadın, ana, valide, kocakarı, mader, nene, aba",
    "gos": "0",
    "ozelliklerListe": [
      {
        "ozellik_id": "19",
        "tur": "3",
        "tam_adi": "isim",
        "kisa_adi": "a.",
        "ekno": "30"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "anlam_id": "4799",
    "madde_id": "9592",
    "anlam_sira": "2",
    "fiil": "0",
    "tipkes": "0",
    "anlam": "Yavrusu olan dişi hayvan",
    "gos": "0"
  }
]
```

Comment: Check that `Anlamlar_Liste[Sıra_Numarası].ozelliklerListe` isn't `undefined` before you try to call `forEach` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the objects in your array don't have a `ozelliklerListe` property. So check for this before trying to use it.

```
Anlamlar_Liste.forEach(anlamlar => {
  if (anlamlar.ozelliklerListe) {
    anlamlar.ozelliklerListe.forEach(Özellik => {
      Tepki_Mesajı.addField(`${Sıra_Numarası + 1}. ${Özellik.tam_adi}`, Anlamlar_Liste[Sıra_Numarası].anlam, true)
      console.log(Özellik.tam_adi)
      console.log(Anlamlar_Liste[Sıra_Numarası].ozelliklerListe)
    })
  }
});
```